# Adjust brightness on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, backlight

I like to adjust my backlight. There for I was trying to use

```
sudo apt-get install -y xbacklight
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xbacklight is already the newest version (1.2.1-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

without any success. It follows my graphic-card and the driver:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G73 [GeForce 7600 GT] [10de:0391] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

And here comes my current settings for brightness and resolution:

```
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
```

Comment: What happens when you try `xbacklight -set 30`?

Comment: `$ xbacklight -set 30`  
`No outputs have backlight property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deinstalled backlight and using te command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness;
```

to set baklight to "1". I can use a integer in the range 1 to 15.